# How can i update the text in one table column according to the slider change in previous table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slider and a text input. There's a default value for the text input, i want to make the number displayed in the text input change when i slide the slider to a different percentage. I am wondering which tag i should use that i could set a default value to it and it won't be affected by the changing result. I have it in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8DzCE/269/

```
       <table id="foodaverage" style>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Average amount</td>
                <td></td>
                <td><div id="foodcarb" style="display: inline;">carbon footprint( <p id="unit" style="font-size: 10px; display: inline;">tons CO<sub>2</sub>)</p></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="simpleslider" class="slide"></div></td>
                <td><div id="simplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="528" class="result" id="foodanswer" /></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div id="qslider" class="slide"></div></td>
                    <td><div id="asimplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="423" class="result" id="foodanswer1" /></td>
                </tr> 

            </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(".slide").each(function(i,item){
$(item).slider({
    value:50,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    slide: function(event, ui){
        var nextTD = $(this).closest("td").next();

           nextTD.html(ui.value + '&#37;');
         var percent=parseFloat(ui.value);
        var answer=nextTD.closest("input").next();
         var int=parseFloat(answer.val());
        answer.html(int * percent / 100);

    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a data attribute. Some people will argue against these because of lack of accessibility. If thats a problem for you, maybe a hidden field with the same value? I think I'm answering your question here. I was a little unclear.

Something like

```
 <td><input type="text" value="528" data-default="528" class="result" id="foodanswer" /></td>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: then everytime in the calculation i could just use the data-default value to multiply the precentage change ?  the final result will be display in the text and it will change the value attribute ?

Comment: yes. you can definitely do it that way. and if your using jquery for your calculations the function to get data attributes in this case would be $('#foodanswer').data('default');

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
<table id="foodaverage">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Average amount</td>
        <td></td>
        <td><div id="foodcarb" style="display: inline;">carbon footprint( <p id="unit" style="font-size: 10px; display: inline;">tons CO<sub>2</sub>)</p></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="simpleslider" class="slide" data-result="foodanswer" data-default-value="528"></div></td>
        <td><div id="simplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="528" class="result" id="foodanswer" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="qslider" class="slide" data-result="foodanswer1" data-default-value="423"></div></td>
            <td><div id="asimplevalue" class="answer"></div></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="423" class="result" id="foodanswer1" /></td>
     </tr> 
</table>



$(".slide").slider({
        value:50,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui){
            var nextTD = $(this).closest("td").next();                                       
               nextTD.html(ui.value + '&#37;');
        },

        //Fires after the slider's done moving
        change: function(event, ui ){
            var result         = $(this).attr('data-result'),
                defaultValue   = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-default-value')),
                percent        = parseFloat(ui.value);

            $('#'+result).val(defaultValue * percent / 100);

        }

    });
```